# Get date in another timezone of the date which is in indian timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone

I want to get date in another timezone of the date in indian timezone in php. i.e. if the date is 01-02-2013 in indian (+5:30) timezone  What is the date in antoher timezone. ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+DateTime+DateTimeZone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_default_timezone_set`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: will date_default_timezone_set changes a given gate into new timezone ??

Comment: @KrishnaKishore You can: change timezone, calculate the date (Will give it in the timezone you set), and then go back to the old timezone if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) objects.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

echo $date->format('r e'); // Sun, 14 Apr 2013 10:24:55 +0100 Europe/London

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $date->format('r e'); // Sun, 14 Apr 2013 05:26:08 -0400 America/New_York
```

Comment: +1 I'll just add that according to a comment on the [manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.indian.php) India itself is handled by the `Asia/Calcutta` timezone - you may be forgiven for thinking it would be somewhere in the `Indian/*` branch...